# How to convert a zlib stream to PNG?

Tags: c++, c, png, zlib, libpng

I already have a zlib-encoded stream of image data (taken from a PDF /FlateDecode tag). I also got the width and height in pixels as well as color depth (8 bpp). The data is packed RGB.
Now I want to save this as a PNG image (which default compression method is also ZLIB I think?).
I tried adding a PNG header and a IDAT header manually, but it didn't work.
Has anyone an idea, how to to this properly? (libpng ?)

The target system has very limited RAM resources, so decoding the zlib data and re-encoding with libpng is off the table.

Comment: What format is the image data?

Comment: The image data is zlib-encoded packed rgb data. ("raw")

Comment: If you're asking what library and its functions should you use, then this is off-topic. If you are asking how to roll your own implementation, then this is too broad. Also _"but it didn't work."_ is highly insufficient a description of an error

Comment: @PasserBy The question seemed fine to me, where the question was explicitly about doing it _without_ a library, and I figured out exactly what was being tried and what the error was. Whether a question is clear or not is apparently in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: @MarkAdler: if OP had shared the relevant part of their code, there'd be a fair chance we could tell what the problem is with it. As it is, this question comes down to "I have code but it doesn't work, please write some."

Comment: @usr2564301 Hmm. I do not see the request you see to please write some code for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to decompress, reformat the data for PNG, and recompress. The image data that is compressed in a PNG file is not simply the raw RGB data. Per [the specification](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IDAT), each line of the image is preceded by a filter byte, which specifies how that line is differenced (or not) from previous data. Even if you do no differencing, you need that byte to say that. However you will get much better compression with one of the filter modes.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I understand. I am going to inflate block-wise now and recompress with libpng.